# Named placeholders in string formatting

Tags: java, string-formatting

In Python, when formatting string, I can fill placeholders by name rather than by position, like that:

```
print "There's an incorrect value '%(value)s' in column # %(column)d" % \
  { 'value': x, 'column': y }
```

I wonder if that is possible in Java (hopefully, without external libraries)?

Comment: You might extend MessageFormat and implement the mapping funtionality from variables to indices in that.

Comment: See StrSubstitutor - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html

Comment: Some history: Java mostly copied C/C++ on this matter as it tried to lure developers from the C++ world where `%s` was common practice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#History
Also note that some IDE and FindBugs may automatically detect mismatching %s and %d counts, but I would still prefer named fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for all your help! Using all your clues, I've written routine to do exactly what I want -- python-like string formatting using dictionary. Since I'm Java newbie, any hints are appreciated.

```
public static String dictFormat(String format, Hashtable<String, Object> values) {
    StringBuilder convFormat = new StringBuilder(format);
    Enumeration<String> keys = values.keys();
    ArrayList valueList = new ArrayList();
    int currentPos = 1;
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = keys.nextElement(),
        formatKey = "%(" + key + ")",
        formatPos = "%" + Integer.toString(currentPos) + "$";
        int index = -1;
        while ((index = convFormat.indexOf(formatKey, index)) != -1) {
            convFormat.replace(index, index + formatKey.length(), formatPos);
            index += formatPos.length();
        }
        valueList.add(values.get(key));
        ++currentPos;
    }
    return String.format(convFormat.toString(), valueList.toArray());
}
```

Comment: Unlike in Lombo's answer, this cannot get stuck in an infinite loop, since `formatPos` can't contain `formatKey`.

Comment: **Warning:** Because the loop treats intermediate substitution results as format strings of their own, [this solution is vulnerable to format string attacks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194454/9357). Any correct solution should make one single pass through the format string.

Answer (score 179):

[`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) from *Apache Commons Text* library is a lightweight way of doing this, provided your values are already formatted correctly.

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("value", "1");
values.put("column","2");

StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(values, "%(", ")");
String result = sub.replace("There's an incorrect value '%(value)' in column # %(column)");
```

The `result` string will contain the following:

> `There's an incorrect value '1' in column # 2`

When using Maven you can add this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I found it disappointing that the library doesn't throw if keys are not found, however, if you use the default syntax (`${arg}`) instead of the custom one above (`%(arg)`) then the regex will not compile, which is the desired effect.

Comment: You can set a custom VariableResolver and throw an Exception if the key isn't present in the map.

Comment: Old thread, but as of 3.6, the text package was deprecated in favor of commons-text. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/

Comment: StringSubstitutor in Apache Commons Text now (2022) appears to be the current version of the above

Comment: @BrianAgnew Exactly. Updated the solution to reflect the current state of things.

Answer (score 105):

not quite, but you can use [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) to reference one value multiple times:

```
MessageFormat.format("There's an incorrect value \"{0}\" in column # {1}", x, y);
```

The above can be done with String.format() as well, but I find messageFormat syntax cleaner if you need to build complex expressions, plus you dont need to care about the type of the object you are putting into the string

Comment: not sure why you can't, the position in the string is not important, only the position in the list of args, which makes it a renaming problem. You know the name of the keys, which means you can decide a position for a key in the list of arguments.     
from now on value will be known as 0 and column as 1:
     MessageeFormat.format("There's an incorrect value \"{0}\" in column # {1}, using {0} as value can cause many problems", valueMap.get('value'), valueMap.get('column'));

Comment: Thanks for a clue, it helped me to write simple function that does exactly what I want (I've put it below).

Comment: Agreed, the syntax is much cleaner. Too bad MessageFormat has got a mind of its own when it comes to formatting numeric values.

Comment: And it seems to ignore placeholders surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: `MessageFormat` is great but cumbersome for relatively large json content

Comment: That didnt work for me at all imported `java.text.MessageFormat` and it is not mapping to `{0}` any clue?

Comment: This changed my life

Comment: What if your strings are dynamic @giladbu? I feel like this only works easily if you have static message strings that are being interpolated.

Comment: Also String.format uses regexp, and if your template has reserved characters you should escape them.

Answer (score 58):

Another example of Apache Common [StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) for simple named placeholder.

```
String template = "Welcome to {theWorld}. My name is {myName}.";

Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("theWorld", "Stackoverflow");
values.put("myName", "Thanos");

String message = StringSubstitutor.replace(template, values, "{", "}");

System.out.println(message);

// Welcome to Stackoverflow. My name is Thanos.
```

Comment: If you expect to load very large files, I found this library also supports `replaceIn` which substitutes values into a buffer: StringBuilder, or TextStringBuilder. With this approach, the entire contents of the file won't be loaded into memory.

Comment: no offense. To format a string in a replace way is very unreasonable and unreadable. Especially compares with other modern program languages.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [StringTemplate](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST/Introduction) library, it offers what you want and much more.

```
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

final StringTemplate hello = new StringTemplate("Hello, $name$");
hello.setAttribute("name", "World");
System.out.println(hello.toString());
```

Comment: Had trouble with the `'` char: `unexpected char: '''`

Answer (score 14):

```
public static String format(String format, Map<String, Object> values) {
    StringBuilder formatter = new StringBuilder(format);
    List<Object> valueList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)}").matcher(format);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);

        String formatKey = String.format("${%s}", key);
        int index = formatter.indexOf(formatKey);

        if (index != -1) {
            formatter.replace(index, index + formatKey.length(), "%s");
            valueList.add(values.get(key));
        }
    }

    return String.format(formatter.toString(), valueList.toArray());
}
```

Example:

```
String format = "My name is ${1}. ${0} ${1}.";

Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
values.put("0", "James");
values.put("1", "Bond");

System.out.println(format(format, values)); // My name is Bond. James Bond.
```

Comment: This should be the answer, since it avoids the format string attacks that most of the other solutions here are vulnerable to. Note that Java 9 makes it much simpler, with support for [`.replaceAll()` string substitution callbacks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.util.function.Function%29).

Comment: This should be the answer, for that it doesn't use any external libraries.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread, but just for the record, you could also use Java 8 style, like this:

```
public static String replaceParams(Map<String, String> hashMap, String template) {
    return hashMap.entrySet().stream().reduce(template, (s, e) -> s.replace("%(" + e.getKey() + ")", e.getValue()),
            (s, s2) -> s);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put("foo", "foo1");
            put("bar", "bar1");
            put("car", "BMW");
            put("truck", "MAN");
        }
    };
    String res = replaceParams(hashMap, "This is '%(foo)' and '%(foo)', but also '%(bar)' '%(bar)' indeed.");
    System.out.println(res);
    System.out.println(replaceParams(hashMap, "This is '%(car)' and '%(foo)', but also '%(bar)' '%(bar)' indeed."));
    System.out.println(replaceParams(hashMap, "This is '%(car)' and '%(truck)', but also '%(foo)' '%(bar)' + '%(truck)' indeed."));
}
```

The output will be:

```
This is 'foo1' and 'foo1', but also 'bar1' 'bar1' indeed.
This is 'BMW' and 'foo1', but also 'bar1' 'bar1' indeed.
This is 'BMW' and 'MAN', but also 'foo1' 'bar1' + 'MAN' indeed.
```

Comment: This is brilliant, but sadly it violates the specs here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-
The combiner function must return the second parameter if the first param is the identity. The one above would return the identity instead.
It also violates this rule: combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)

Comment: Interesting ... but only if you propose a nicer way to pass the map, also if possible after the template like most formatting code.

Comment: **Warning:** Because the `.reduce()` treats intermediate substitution results as format strings of their own, [this solution is vulnerable to format string attacks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194454/9357). Any correct solution should make one single pass through the format string.

Answer (score 6):

[Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)'s [`StringSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) can be used. (See [Dependency Information](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/dependency-info.html) for how to include it in a project.) Note that `StrSubstitutor` is deprecated.

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;
// ...
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
values.put("target", "lazy dog");
StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(values);
String result = sub.replace("The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.");
// "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
```

This class supports providing default values for variables.

```
String result = sub.replace("The number is ${undefined.property:-42}.");
// "The number is 42."
```

To use recursive variable replacement, call `setEnableSubstitutionInVariables(true);`.

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("b", "c");
values.put("ac", "Test");
StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(values);
sub.setEnableSubstitutionInVariables(true);
String result = sub.replace("${a${b}}");
// "Test"
```

Answer (score 5):

I am the author of [a small library](https://github.com/nomemory/aleph-formatter) that does exactly what you want:

```
Student student = new Student("Andrei", 30, "Male");

String studStr = template("#{id}\tName: #{st.getName}, Age: #{st.getAge}, Gender: #{st.getGender}")
                    .arg("id", 10)
                    .arg("st", student)
                    .format();
System.out.println(studStr);
```

Or you can chain the arguments:

```
String result = template("#{x} + #{y} = #{z}")
                    .args("x", 5, "y", 10, "z", 15)
                    .format();
System.out.println(result);

// Output: "5 + 10 = 15"
```

Comment: is it possible to do condition based formatting with your library?

Comment: @gaurav not quite. If you need that you need a full-featured templating library.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built into Java at the moment of writing this. I would suggest writing your own implementation. My preference is for a simple fluent builder interface instead of creating a map and passing it to function -- you end up with a nice contiguous chunk of code, for example:

```
String result = new TemplatedStringBuilder("My name is {{name}} and I from {{town}}")
   .replace("name", "John Doe")
   .replace("town", "Sydney")
   .finish();
```

Here is a simple implementation:

```
class TemplatedStringBuilder {

    private final static String TEMPLATE_START_TOKEN = "{{";
    private final static String TEMPLATE_CLOSE_TOKEN = "}}";

    private final String template;
    private final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();

    public TemplatedStringBuilder(String template) {
        if (template == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.template = template;
    }

    public TemplatedStringBuilder replace(String key, String value){
        parameters.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    public String finish(){

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        int startIndex = 0;

        while (startIndex < template.length()){

            int openIndex  = template.indexOf(TEMPLATE_START_TOKEN, startIndex);

            if (openIndex < 0){
                result.append(template.substring(startIndex));
                break;
            }

            int closeIndex = template.indexOf(TEMPLATE_CLOSE_TOKEN, openIndex);

            if(closeIndex < 0){
                result.append(template.substring(startIndex));
                break;
            }

            String key = template.substring(openIndex + TEMPLATE_START_TOKEN.length(), closeIndex);

            if (!parameters.containsKey(key)) throw new RuntimeException("missing value for key: " + key);

            result.append(template.substring(startIndex, openIndex));
            result.append(parameters.get(key));

            startIndex = closeIndex + TEMPLATE_CLOSE_TOKEN.length();
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Lang's [replaceEach](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) method may come in handy dependeding on your specific needs. You can easily use it to replace placeholders by name with this single method call:

```
StringUtils.replaceEach("There's an incorrect value '%(value)' in column # %(column)",
            new String[] { "%(value)", "%(column)" }, new String[] { x, y });
```

Given some input text, this will replace all occurrences of the placeholders in the first string array with the corresponding values in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the official [ICU4J library](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/master/icu4j). It provides a [MessageFormat](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4j/) class similar to the one available with the JDK but this former supports named placeholders.

Unlike other solutions provided on this page. ICU4j is part of the [ICU project](http://site.icu-project.org/) that is maintained by IBM and regularly updated. In addition, it supports advanced use cases such as pluralization and much more.

Here is a code example:

```
MessageFormat messageFormat =
        new MessageFormat("Publication written by {author}.");

Map<String, String> args = Map.of("author", "John Doe");

System.out.println(messageFormat.format(args));
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022 the up-to-date solution is Apache Commons Text [StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html)

From the doc:

```
// Build map
 Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
 valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
 valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
 String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target} ${undefined.number:-1234567890} times.";

 // Build StringSubstitutor
 StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);

 // Replace
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString)
```

;

Comment: My preferred answer so far. Permissive license (suitable for both FOSS and proprietary projects), and from a source I would trust to produce mature code and still be around tomorrow. Minor one: for a one-off replacement, `StringSubstitutor.replace (templateString, valuesMap);` is even quicker.

Answer (score 2):

If use of a map is not a requirement, then you can use Java's String Templates feature.
It is described in [JEP 430](https://openjdk.org/jeps/430), and it appears in JDK 21 as a preview feature.  Here is an example use:

```java
String s = STR."There's an incorrect value '\{x}' in column # \{y}";
```

Java's string templates are more versatile, and much safer, than features in other languagues such as C#'s string interpolation and Python's f-strings.
For example, string concatenation or interpolation makes SQL injection attacks possible:

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = '" + name + "'";
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
```

but this variant (from JEP 430) prevents SQL injection:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = DB."SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE p.last_name = \{name}";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like this on a string helper class

```
/**
 * An interpreter for strings with named placeholders.
 *
 * For example given the string "hello %(myName)" and the map <code>
 *      <p>Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();</p>
 *      <p>map.put("myName", "world");</p>
 * </code>
 *
 * the call {@code format("hello %(myName)", map)} returns "hello world"
 *
 * It replaces every occurrence of a named placeholder with its given value
 * in the map. If there is a named place holder which is not found in the
 * map then the string will retain that placeholder. Likewise, if there is
 * an entry in the map that does not have its respective placeholder, it is
 * ignored.
 *
 * @param str
 *            string to format
 * @param values
 *            to replace
 * @return formatted string
 */
public static String format(String str, Map<String, Object> values) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : values.entrySet()) {

        int start;
        String pattern = "%(" + entry.getKey() + ")";
        String value = entry.getValue().toString();

        // Replace every occurence of %(key) with value
        while ((start = builder.indexOf(pattern)) != -1) {
            builder.replace(start, start + pattern.length(), value);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does almost what I want, but the only thing is it does not account modifiers (consider "%(key)08d")

Comment: Note also that this goes into an infinite loop if any of the values being used contain the corresponding entry.

Comment: **Warning:** Because the loop treats intermediate substitution results as format strings of their own, [this solution is vulnerable to format string attacks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194454/9357). Any correct solution should make one single pass through the format string.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17474581/3042543) I created `MapBuilder` class:

```
public class MapBuilder {

    public static Map<String, Object> build(Object... data) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        if (data.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Odd number of arguments");
        }

        String key = null;
        Integer step = -1;

        for (Object value : data) {
            step++;
            switch (step % 2) {
                case 0:
                    if (value == null) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key value");
                    }
                    key = (String) value;
                    continue;
                case 1:
                    result.put(key, value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

then I created class `StringFormat` for String formatting:

```
public final class StringFormat {

    public static String format(String format, Object... args) {
        Map<String, Object> values = MapBuilder.build(args);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : values.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            format = format.replace("$" + key, value.toString());
        }

        return format;
    }

}
```

which you could use like that:

```
String bookingDate = StringFormat.format("From $startDate to $endDate"), 
        "$startDate", formattedStartDate, 
        "$endDate", formattedEndDate
);
```

Comment: **Warning:** Because the loop treats intermediate substitution results as format strings of their own, [this solution is vulnerable to format string attacks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194454/9357). Any correct solution should make one single pass through the format string.

Answer (score 1):

I created also a util/helper class (using jdk 8) which can format a string an replaces occurrences of variables.

For this purpose I used the Matchers "appendReplacement" method which does all the substitution and loops only over the affected parts of a format string.

The helper class isn't currently well javadoc documented. I will changes this in the future ;)
Anyway I commented the most important lines (I hope).

```
    public class FormatHelper {

    //Prefix and suffix for the enclosing variable name in the format string.
    //Replace the default values with any you need.
    public static final String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "${";
    public static final String DEFAULT_SUFFIX = "}";

    //Define dynamic function what happens if a key is not found.
    //Replace the defualt exception with any "unchecked" exception type you need or any other behavior.
    public static final BiFunction<String, String, String> DEFAULT_NO_KEY_FUNCTION =
            (fullMatch, variableName) -> {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Key: %s for variable %s not found.",
                                                         variableName,
                                                         fullMatch));
            };
    private final Pattern variablePattern;
    private final Map<String, String> values;
    private final BiFunction<String, String, String> noKeyFunction;
    private final String prefix;
    private final String suffix;

    public FormatHelper(Map<String, String> values) {
        this(DEFAULT_NO_KEY_FUNCTION, values);
    }

    public FormatHelper(
            BiFunction<String, String, String> noKeyFunction, Map<String, String> values) {
        this(DEFAULT_PREFIX, DEFAULT_SUFFIX, noKeyFunction, values);
    }

    public FormatHelper(String prefix, String suffix, Map<String, String> values) {
        this(prefix, suffix, DEFAULT_NO_KEY_FUNCTION, values);
    }

    public FormatHelper(
            String prefix,
            String suffix,
            BiFunction<String, String, String> noKeyFunction,
            Map<String, String> values) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        this.values = values;
        this.noKeyFunction = noKeyFunction;

        //Create the Pattern and quote the prefix and suffix so that the regex don't interpret special chars.
        //The variable name is a "\w+" in an extra capture group.
        variablePattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(prefix) + "(\\w+)" + Pattern.quote(suffix));
    }

    public static String format(CharSequence format, Map<String, String> values) {
        return new FormatHelper(values).format(format);
    }

    public static String format(
            CharSequence format,
            BiFunction<String, String, String> noKeyFunction,
            Map<String, String> values) {
        return new FormatHelper(noKeyFunction, values).format(format);
    }

    public static String format(
            String prefix, String suffix, CharSequence format, Map<String, String> values) {
        return new FormatHelper(prefix, suffix, values).format(format);
    }

    public static String format(
            String prefix,
            String suffix,
            BiFunction<String, String, String> noKeyFunction,
            CharSequence format,
            Map<String, String> values) {
        return new FormatHelper(prefix, suffix, noKeyFunction, values).format(format);
    }

    public String format(CharSequence format) {

        //Create matcher based on the init pattern for variable names.
        Matcher matcher = variablePattern.matcher(format);

        //This buffer will hold all parts of the formatted finished string.
        StringBuffer formatBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        //loop while the matcher finds another variable (prefix -> name <- suffix) match
        while (matcher.find()) {

            //The root capture group with the full match e.g ${variableName}
            String fullMatch = matcher.group();

            //The capture group for the variable name resulting from "(\w+)" e.g. variableName
            String variableName = matcher.group(1);

            //Get the value in our Map so the Key is the used variable name in our "format" string. The associated value will replace the variable.
            //If key is missing (absent) call the noKeyFunction with parameters "fullMatch" and "variableName" else return the value.
            String value = values.computeIfAbsent(variableName, key -> noKeyFunction.apply(fullMatch, key));

            //Escape the Map value because the "appendReplacement" method interprets the $ and \ as special chars.
            String escapedValue = Matcher.quoteReplacement(value);

            //The "appendReplacement" method replaces the current "full" match (e.g. ${variableName}) with the value from the "values" Map.
            //The replaced part of the "format" string is appended to the StringBuffer "formatBuffer".
            matcher.appendReplacement(formatBuffer, escapedValue);
        }

        //The "appendTail" method appends the last part of the "format" String which has no regex match.
        //That means if e.g. our "format" string has no matches the whole untouched "format" string is appended to the StringBuffer "formatBuffer".
        //Further more the method return the buffer.
        return matcher.appendTail(formatBuffer)
                      .toString();
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}
```

You can create a class instance for a specific Map with values (or suffix prefix or noKeyFunction)
like:

```
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("firstName", "Peter");
    values.put("lastName", "Parker");


    FormatHelper formatHelper = new FormatHelper(values);
    formatHelper.format("${firstName} ${lastName} is Spiderman!");
    // Result: "Peter Parker is Spiderman!"
    // Next format:
    formatHelper.format("Does ${firstName} ${lastName} works as photographer?");
    //Result: "Does Peter Parker works as photographer?"
```

Further more you can define what happens if a key in the values Map is missing (works in both ways e.g. wrong variable name in format string or missing key in Map).
The default behavior is an thrown unchecked exception (unchecked because I use the default jdk8 Function which cant handle checked exceptions) like:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("firstName", "Peter");
    map.put("lastName", "Parker");


    FormatHelper formatHelper = new FormatHelper(map);
    formatHelper.format("${missingName} ${lastName} is Spiderman!");
    //Result: RuntimeException: Key: missingName for variable ${missingName} not found.
```

You can define a custom behavior in the constructor call like:

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("firstName", "Peter");
values.put("lastName", "Parker");


FormatHelper formatHelper = new FormatHelper(fullMatch, variableName) -> variableName.equals("missingName") ? "John": "SOMETHING_WRONG", values);
formatHelper.format("${missingName} ${lastName} is Spiderman!");
// Result: "John Parker is Spiderman!"
```

or delegate it back to the default no key behavior:

```
...
    FormatHelper formatHelper = new FormatHelper((fullMatch, variableName) ->   variableName.equals("missingName") ? "John" :
            FormatHelper.DEFAULT_NO_KEY_FUNCTION.apply(fullMatch,
                                                       variableName), map);
...
```

For better handling there are also static method representations like:

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("firstName", "Peter");
values.put("lastName", "Parker");

FormatHelper.format("${firstName} ${lastName} is Spiderman!", map);
// Result: "Peter Parker is Spiderman!"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is Java Plugin to use string interpolation in Java (like in Kotlin, JavaScript). Supports Java 8, 9, 10, 11…​ https://github.com/antkorwin/better-strings

**Using variables in string literals:**

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
System.out.println("${a} + ${b} = ${a+b}");
```

**Using expressions:**

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
System.out.println("pow = ${a * a}");
System.out.println("flag = ${a > b ? true : false}");
```

**Using functions:**

```
@Test
void functionCall() {
    System.out.println("fact(5) = ${factorial(5)}");
}

long factorial(int n) {
    long fact = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

For more info, please read the project README.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is no, unfortunately. However, you can come pretty close to a reasonable syntaks:

```
"""
   You are $compliment!
"""
.replace('$compliment', 'awesome');
```

It's more readable and predictable than `String.format`, at least!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/), templating library.

[image]

Comment: Freemarker? i guess he is willing to know, how to do this in plain java. Anyways if Freemarker is the probable answer then can i say JSP too will be the correct answer?

Comment: Thanks, but for my task at hand this seems to be kind of overkill. But thanks.

Comment: @Rakesh JSP is a very "view/FE" specific thing. I have used FreeMarker in the past for generating XML and sometimes even generated JAVA files. Andy am afraid you will have to write one utility yourself (or like the one prescribed above)

Comment: @Boris which one is better freemarker vs velocity vs stringtemplate?

Comment: @gaurav take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741618/what-are-the-main-differences-between-stringtemplate-and-freemarker and https://dzone.com/articles/template-engines-review-after-deprecated-velocity

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to:

a) use StringBuilder when possible

b) keep (in any form: integer is the best, speciall char like dollar macro etc) position of "placeholder" and then use `StringBuilder.insert()` (few versions of arguments).

Using external libraries seems overkill and I belive degrade performance significant, when StringBuilder is converted to String internally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in just a quick way

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String rowString = "replace the value ${var1} with ${var2}";
    
    Map<String,String> mappedValues = new HashMap<>();
    
    mappedValues.put("var1", "Value 1");
    mappedValues.put("var2", "Value 2");
    
    System.out.println(replaceOccurence(rowString, mappedValues));
}

private static  String replaceOccurence(String baseStr ,Map<String,String> mappedValues)
{
    for(String key :mappedValues.keySet())
    {
        baseStr = baseStr.replace("${"+key+"}", mappedValues.get(key));
    }
    
    return baseStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the next solution:
Create class `TemplateSubstitutor` with method `substitute()` and use it to format output
Then create a string template and fill it with values

```java
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String template = "WRR = {WRR}, SRR = {SRR}\n" +
                      "char_F1 = {char_F1}, word_F1 = {word_F1}\n";
    
    Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("WRR", 99.9);
    values.put("SRR", 99.8);
    values.put("char_F1", 80);
    values.put("word_F1", 70);
    
    String message = TemplateSubstitutor.substitute(values, template);
    
    System.out.println(message);
    }
}

class TemplateSubstitutor {
    public static String substitute(Map<String, Object> map, String input_str) {
        String output_str = input_str;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            output_str = output_str.replace("{" + key + "}", String.valueOf(value));
        }
        return output_str;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples String.format(inputString, [listOfParams]) would be the easiest way. Placeholders in string can be defined by order. For more details check the provided link.