# how to read from file raw and use in String.format

Tags: android, string, string-formatting

I want to read data from a raw file and replace the format in the text.

For example... In a raw file like this:

```
hello {0}, my name id {1}, my age is {2}....
```

When I use String.format, as shown below, the text loses its indentation.

```
String data = readTextFile(this, R.raw.input);
data = String.format(data, "world", "josh", "3");
```

Does anyone know how to do this without losing indentation?

Comment: 1st, i think this `{0} {1} ...` will not work, java uses `%d` for digits, and `%s` for string , 2nd, what do you men by `text loses its indentation` ? can you post both expected and actual output ?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a file? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887690/2308683

Comment: because I have a large text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

there is a needed in one more variable, it's impossible to assignment into same variable

```
String data = readTextFile(this, R.raw.input);
String output = String.format(data, "world", "josh", "3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Code that you provided looks more like String.format e.g from [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). String.format in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) does not work this way, it's more like printf.

You can manipulate your input to looks like this.

```
String input = "hello %s, my name id %s, my age is %s";
String.format(input, "world", "josh", "3");
```

output:
`hello world, my name id josh, my age is 3`

indentation should be the same

**EDIT**

If you want to use brackets you can use `MessageFormat.format` instead of `String.format`.

```
String messageInput = "hello {0}, my name id {1}, my age is {2}";
MessageFormat.format(messageInput,"world", "josh", "3");
```

Comment: Actually Java does support that ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324007/java-equivalent-of-pythons-format

Comment: is there possible to use more then one time in the  brackets,
 I mean:
String messageInput = "hello {0}, my name id {1}, my age is {0}";
MessageFormat.format(messageInput,"world", "josh");

Comment: @chaim yes there is

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Explessions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with pattern like that: `"{/d++}"`:

```
String format (String input, String... args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("{/d++}");
    String[] parts = p.split(input);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    int limit = Math.min(args.length, parts.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        builder.append(parts[i]).append(args[i]);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```