# How to do string formatting with placeholders in Java (like in Python)?

Tags: java, python, string, format, placeholder

I am new to Java and am from Python. In Python we do string formatting like this:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> y = 5
>>> print("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(x, y, x + y))
4 + 5 = 9
>>> print("{} {}".format(x,y))
4 5
```

How do I replicate the same thing in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Named placeholders in string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class looks like what you're after.

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} + {1} = {2}", x, y, x + y));
```

Comment: With the caveat that `MessageFormat.format` does not handle the empty place holder `{}`.

Comment: ... and the caveat that if you use `'{` it won't recognise the brackets

Answer (score 12):

Java has a [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method that works similarly to this.  [Here's an example of how to use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695253/61624)  This is the [documentation reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) that explains what all those `%` options can be.

And here's an inlined example:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("It is %d oclock", 5));
    }        
}
```

This prints "It is 5 oclock".

Comment: This `%` based string formatting is similar to [old-style formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) used in python, OP is using the [new-style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: Ah, from the question I didn't know he was putting that much emphasis on using curly brackets.  I thought he just wanted a way to format a string without concatenating strings and variables together.

Comment: Thanks for the comment btw.  Otherwise I wouldn't have understood why @rgettman was getting so many upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

Slf4j has [MessageFormatter.format()](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.html) that accepts `{}` without the argument number, just like Python. Slf4j is a popular logging framework, but you don't have to use it for logging to use MessageFormatter.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use empty placeholders (without positions), you could write a small utility around `Message.format()`, like this

```
    void print(String s, Object... var2) {
        int i = 0;
        while(s.contains("{}")) {
            s = s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("{}"), "{"+ i++ +"}");
        }
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(s, var2));
    }
```

And then, can use it like,

```
print("{} + {} = {}", 4, 5, 4 + 5);
```

Comment: I like this approach. But I would put this into a Formatter class with a format method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (using [String.format)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
int x = 4;
int y = 5;

String res = String.format("%d + %d = %d", x, y, x+y);
System.out.println(res); // prints "4 + 5 = 9"

res = String.format("%d %d", x, y);
System.out.println(res); // prints "4 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Log4j 2 (`log4j-api`) then you can use [`ParameterizedMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-).

```java
ParameterizedMessage.format("{} {}", new Object[] {x, y});
```

or

```java
new ParameterizedMessage("{} {}", x, y).getFormattedMessage(); // there is trimming
```