# Named placeholders in Android

Tags: android, string-formatting

In my android app
in message if i give message "hi #name,welcome your username:#username and password:#password" and in message #name,#username,#password are to be replaced with values iam reading from csv file
and it should send message as example:"hi praveen,welcome your username:neevarp and password:12345" 
and those values are from csv .while searching i got some link

[Named placeholders in string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting)

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("value", x);
values.put("column", y);
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(values, "%(", ")");
String result = sub.replace("There's an incorrect value '%(value)' in column # %(column)");
```

but in android

> StrSubstitutor
>   class is not there i think so is there any way to implement this

here is my code of reading values from csv and sending messages by replacing place holders

```
      public void sendingSms(String message, String file_path) {

    File file = new File("", file_path);

    // Read text from file

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        int iteration = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (iteration != 0) {

                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                text.append(line);
                String[] contact = text.toString().split(",");
                String phoneNumber = contact[4];
                String name = contact[1];
                String username = contact[2];
                String password = contact[3];
      //here i have to replace place holders with name,username,password values
                //message.replace("#name", name);
                //message.replace("#user", username);

                Toast.makeText(Message.this, "" + message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null,
                 null);

            }
            iteration++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using the built in string formatting Android provides via string resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: hey Alex Fu ,i have added my code i am not sure how it is useful, can you please explain me how it will be useful in my case

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you want is built right into the String class itself if you want to design your own StrSubstitutor class.  Essentially building/designing a foreach with your Mapped values into the function.

```
String result = inputString.replace(valueString, replacedValueString);
```

But I am unaware of the function that you are requesting being built-in. Alex Fu as well has provided alternate means by which you could handle your string replacement.