# java format string without all parameters

Tags: java, string, formatting

If I have the next string template:

```
String test_template   = "\"%1$s\" (%2$s) (%3$s)";
```

Is there any way I can format it with 3rd parameter only?

```
MessageFormat.format(test_template, *here put only 3rd parameter*);
```

Comment: pass in two empty strings then your desired one?

Comment: I suppose you could split the test_template string by spaces and store it in an array, then you could just put the third element of that array as the format.

Comment: beresfordt, no. In this case I will lose 1st and 2nd templates. I want to leave %1$s and %2$s and substitute only 3rd

Comment: How about `MessageFormat.format(test_template, "%1$s", "%2$s", "foo");`?

Comment: I don't understand why you use this template in the first place, if you want to replace only third part. I suppose, you mean to replace them one by one. In that case, run three `MessageFormat.format()` commands and combine the results in a fourth call format("{0}{2}{3}", res1, res2, res3).

Comment: McDowell, this is what I was looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
String test_template2   = "{0} {1} {2}";
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(test_template2,"first","second", "third"));
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(test_template2,"","", "third"));
```

The output will be:

"first second third"

"  third"

Hope helped you!

If you want to use named placeholder you can read about how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting)