# Replace 2 parts in a single string with other string using JAVA

Tags: java

I have a string like:

```
{abc} say hello to {def};
```

or

```
You say hello to {abc};
```

Now I want to replace this sentence like this:

```
Peter say hello to Sally;
```

or

```
You say hello to Peter
```

which {abc} and {def} are user's ID, so I need to get the string inside { }. Then replace these words. How can I get the words inside { }

I tried to use .indexOf and .substring to make it work. But I think it is not a good idea as it need a lot of codes to handle two kinds. 
My method:

```
String sentence = {abc} say hello to {def};
int firstOpen = sentence.indexOf("{");
int firstClose = sentence.indexOf("}");
int secondOpen = sentence.lastIndexOf("{");
int secondClose = sentence.lastIndexOf("}");
String firstName = sentence.subSting(firstOpen + 1, firstClose);
String secondName = sentence.subSting(secondOpen + 1, secondClose);
...
sentence = "Peter" + sentence.substring(firstClose, secondOpen) .....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named placeholders in string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not sure what word would be inside curly braces, then you can use these regex to make them generic

```
input = input.replaceFirst("^\\{([^}]*)\\}", "Peter").replaceFirst("\\{([^}]*)\\};$", "Sally");
```

Output:

```
Peter say hello to Sally
```

---

You can use this program if you want to save the group ids.

**Output**

```
first Id: abc                                                                                                                                                                                              
second Id: def                                                                                                                                                                                             
replaced String: Peter say hello to Sally
```

**Code #2**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "{abc} say hello to {def};";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\{([^}]*)\\}(.*)\\{([^}]*)\\};$").matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("first Id: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("second Id: " + m.group(3));
            System.out.println("replaced String: " + "Peter" + m.group(2) + "Sally");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The braces contain user's ID, so "Peter" and "Sally" is the names corresponding to ID. So I need to read the ID first.

Comment: How do you want to read `id`, you want to save it in a String variable?

Comment: No, I don't need to save it. I just wanna to use it to get date from database.

Comment: I don't know any about Matcher. I just tried it. m.find return false. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @YunyuenChan I have taken exact same string as you provided and it works as shown in program above. Are you sure the string you provided is exactly the same?

Comment: I know where the problem is. My original string doesn't contain ";"
So I replace the compile part. It works fine now. 
You teach me a lot and save my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use String.replace

```
String output = "{abc} say hello to {def}".replace ("{abc}", "Peter")
                                          .replace ("{def}", "Sally");
```

Comment: Sorry. I miss something from the question. I also need to get the words inside "{ }"

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [String.replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

```
String sentence = "{abc} say hello to {def}";
String firstChange = sentence.replaceFirst("\\{abc\\}","you");
String secondChange = firstChagne.replaceFirst("\\{def\\}","Peter");
```

Comment: `replaceFirst` takes a regex, and `{` and `}` are special characters. This will produce an error unless you escape those characters (i.e. `"\\{abc\\}"`)

Comment: Sorry. I miss something from the question. I also need to get the words inside "{ }"