# How to best parameterize a string

Tags: java, string, replace, parameterization

For example I have:

```
String templateString = "Hi {{customerName}}, you have successfully ordered a {{itemName}}."
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("customerName", "Bob");
parameters.put("itemName", "sofa");
```

Desired output:
`"Hi Bob, you have successfully ordered a sofa."`

What would be the best (foolproof, maintainable, time efficient, etc.) way to get the desired output?

I thought of doing something simple:

```
String output = templateString;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    output = output.replace("{{" + entry.getKey() + "}}", entry.getValue());
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: *What would be the best (foolproof, maintainable, time efficient, etc.) way to get the desired output?* - [To not reinvent the wheel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting)

Comment: Nothing wrong at all with your current attempt.  What are you looking for here?  Note that there are already Java template libraries which can do this.

Comment: And there is also the built-in solution using  [`printf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Comment: How about `"Hi " + var1 + " Bye " + var2 + " !! "`

Comment: You can use built in `String.format()`.

Comment: @Turing85 It doesn't support named parameters, which is what the OP is asking for I guess

Comment: to all: First, study the task. Before decrementing of the question.

Comment: Tim is correct: [Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) for example does exactly this. Lots of very large companies have used it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how sophisticated a templating system you need. There are many out there already.

Two examples are:

- [String Template](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `Mustache.java`, [docs](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java)

```
String templateString = "Hi {{customerName}}, you have successfully ordered a {{itemName}}.";
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("customerName", "Bob");
parameters.put("itemName", "sofa");

Writer writer = new StringWriter();
MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache mustache = mf.compile(new StringReader(templateString), "example");
mustache.execute(writer, parameters);
writer.flush();
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to fetch values using keys in Map

```
            String output = templateString;
            output = output.replace("{{customerName}}",parameters.get("customerName"));
            output = output.replace("{{itemName}}",parameters.get("itemName"));
```

Comment: OP is already doing this. The only difference is that he is avoiding hard-coding parameters names instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions already provided in other answers, you can also use `StringSubstitutor` from **Apache Commons Text**.

An example from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html :-

```
 Map valuesMap = HashMap();
 valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
 valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
 String templateString = "The ${animal} jumps over the ${target}.";
 StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```