# Build a String object from a template

Tags: java, templates, replace

I've got a String like this:

```
Very long text ... ${ABC} ... very long text ... ${DEF} ...
...
very long text ... ${GHI} ... very long text ...
...
... and so forth ...
```

and I need to replace all these `${...}` with some value (say also such value can be very long) which is stored in a variable of type `String`.

Until now I'm solving it like follows:

```java
String finalString = templateString
                .replaceAll("\\$\\{ABC}", abc)
                .replaceAll("\\$\\{DEF}", def)
                .replaceAll("\\$\\{GHI}", ghi)
                ...
```

but I'm sure it is not the best way of doing this.

I can't use `String.format()` because the template variables are named.

Do you know any way of doing this (maybe using `StringBuilder`?) without using external libraries?

Comment: Take a look at this answer if you don't want to use external libs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286648/named-placeholders-in-string-formatting#answer-27815924

Comment: *but I'm sure it is not the best way of doing this.* <- With the information given, I don't see what's wrong with the regex solution. What exactly are you doubting here? Do you have 17 gazillion variables to replace? Is this in your most inner loop and you suspect it is inefficient?